# Developing a Java Cross platform library (mobile and web)

Tags: android, sockets, java

There are so many cross platform libraries that I am kinda lost to get an answer to a very basic java question.

I have a java library that works well on Android. It does not use any android specific functionality and also builds on the standard java sdk. This library uses sockets (plain simple Socket, ServerSocket kinda architecture) to communicate between the library and a server hosted (may be on a ec2 or some virtual public server).

Now my question is, can other developers import my java library (built using java sdk) to a application that uses html/css for User Interface, package all of this into a mobile application for iPhone (use native iPhone packaging, and a WebView to launch) ? Also can I ship this library so other software developers can build a web application to work on desktops and cross browser's ?

Some questions on stackoverflow are close to what I am looking for, but not quite there.
[Developing Mobile Apps for Multiple Platforms (without a cross-platform framework!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691745/developing-mobile-apps-for-multiple-platforms-without-a-cross-platform-framewor)

- Will a webserver be able to use my library that connects to the server using sockets ?
- And will every client that connects to this webserver create a new instance of my library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you library doesn't use any dependencies on either Android or any other library, another developer can use it pretty much anywhere they want. Although keep in mind that platforms like EC2 may have a preferred way of using communication. (I'm no expert on EC2, so you'll have to see what they use.)

So I guess it's better to abstract out that socket functionality for good.

I don't think you can use a Java library in iPhone. iOS terms of use clearly states that you cannot use a compiler or interpreter on the device other than the one given in the SDK and the webkit javaScript engine in Safari. So there's no way your Java code is going to run on iPhone (without jail-breaking.)

I don't understand the question about webView. Do you mean navigating to a site that is powered by your library ? If yes, then yes as long as you keep it in the boundaries of Safari. (no Flash, no Java Applet .etc.)

> Will a webserver be able to use my library that connects to the server
>   using sockets ?

For the most part, yes. But as I said, the platform may not allow raw connections, so it's good to abstract it out.

> And will every client that connects to this webserver create a new
>   instance of my library ?

This depends on the design of your library and its public APIs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I am one small step closer. Yes, I have abstracted out all the socket stuff into higher level api's like AddUserDetails(name, address, phone_number). Now, is it possible for a servlet to make the AddUserDetails call, which inturn is called from a JSP which inturn is called from html ? This way I can have a html ui, click a button, send name, address and phone number down to the jsp->servlet->mylibrary->socket ? If this is technically possible, I am ready for my product release, and I will party today :) ? Hope I am not sounding too silly.

Comment: Yes. This is quite possible. Although I cannot guarantee without knowing your environment. As long as your library supports plugging in the network part of it, it should be good to go. Even it fails, plug in a different implementation. I think this is how the 'new' GoogleAPIs client library works.
'Write Once Run everywhere' it is.

Comment: Just developed the hello world. I'll post the link of the hello world once its uploaded.